# Can't find how to filter Trello cards but keep showing the other ones slightly grayed-out

Tags: trello

I used to be able to filter cards but keep the rest visible so that I would know where the matched ones are in relation to the others and move them around, but I can't find how to do that anymore. Did they remove this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this feature was removed.  It was not getting very much use compared to filtering with completely hidden cards.

Comment: Maybe that was because it wasn't the default? Defaults tend to be used a lot more. It also wasn't easy to see that the feature existed. I considered it very useful.